# $1/n$ Dehn fill along 5_2 knot

Tags: geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology

Let $S^3-K=M$ where $K$ is $5_2$ knot, now construct a link like bellow the picture[image] now if I start Dehn fill along the link with  a slope $1/n$ for $n=2, 3,4,5,...$ and if know the meridian length of $5_2$ knot(since it is a hyperbolic knot, and M is hyperbolic) then after dehn filling how they meridian length will be change in the knots complements ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does $L$ have to do with your question?